# Find point in 3D space based on plane and known point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

I'm struggling with drawing geometry in 3D spaces via OpenGL. My current task is to find coordinates of point.

[image]

Assume we have such input data:

1. Points $a$, $b$ and $k$ define a plane.
2. Point $c$ lays on plane defined with $a$, $b$ and $k$.
3. Angle between $ab$ and $bc$ is $\beta$ (yellow color on image).
4. Length $bc$ is known value.

How can I find coordinates of $c$?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

Recall that $cb= B-C$, $ab=B-A$ and $ak=K-A$.

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ real numbers such that:
$$cb=\lambda (ab)+ \mu (ak)$$

Define:
$$\theta_2 = \arccos ( \frac{\langle bk, ba\rangle}{\|bk \| \|ba \|})$$
$$p_1=\|cb\|\|ab\| \cos \beta$$
$$p_2=p_1+\|cb\|\|bk\| \cos (\pi- (\theta_2 + \beta))$$
$$D =  \begin{array}{|cc|}
\langle ab,ab \rangle & \langle ak,ab \rangle \\
\langle ak,ab \rangle & \langle ak,ak \rangle \\
\end{array}$$

$$D_{\lambda} =  \begin{array}{|cc|}
p_1 & \langle ak,ab \rangle \\
p_2 & \langle ak,ak \rangle \\
\end{array}$$

$$D_{\mu} =  \begin{array}{|cc|}
\langle ab,ab \rangle & p_1 \\
\langle ak,ab \rangle &p_2 \\
\end{array}$$

Calculate $\lambda$ and $\mu$:

$$\lambda=\frac{D_{\lambda}}{D}$$
$$\mu=\frac{D_{\mu}}{D}$$

A possible point $C$ can be determined by:
$$C=B-\lambda(ab)-\mu(ak)$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the coordinates $c_x,c_y,c_z$ that satisfy

$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&c_x&c_y&c_z\\1&a_x&a_y&a_z\\1&b_x&b_y&b_z\\1&k_x&k_y&k_z\end{matrix}\right|=0,$$

$$(a_x-b_x)(c_x-b_x)+(a_y-b_y)(c_y-b_y)+(a_z-b_z)(c_z-b_z)=rd\cos\beta,$$

$$(c_x-b_x)^2+(c_y-b_y)^2+(c_z-b_z)^2=r^2,$$

where $d$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$, which can be readily computed, and $r$ is the distance between $b$ and $c$, i.e. the length $bc$. The first equation ensures that the point $c$ lies in the plane defined by $a$, $b$ and $k$, the second equation gives the right angle between $ab$ and $bc$, and the third equation is needed to satisfy the distance constraint. I don't know if there is a simple analytical solution of this system, but a numerical solution can be quite easily obtained, in mathematica for instance.